# using non-jni native library in java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, shared

I have a *.so library created without jni headers and i haven't sources of this library. I have to be able to use this library in my java project. Any ideas how to achieve that?

May be it is's possible to create jni library from non-jni library?

There's one tells that it's possible, but he didn't explain how to get it worked: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1552150?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: You could try using [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), or you need to write your own JNI wrapper around it.

Comment: JNA with JNAerator generator looks perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own JNI wrapper shared library. Typically, your Java code will `System.loadLibrary()` your wrapper, and the *dynamic linker* will resolve the references to the original *non-jni* library and **dlopen()** it. This means that you must make sure that both `*.so` files be packaged with your Java app, and the second (*non-jni*) is on the dynamic linker's search path. In some cases, it's easier to call `System.loadLibrary()` or `System.load()` first for the *non-jni* `*.so`, and then for the wrapper.

To write the wrapper, you will need the headers for the *non-jni* library. If you don't have the full header, don't despair: you only need to know how to call the specific public functions of this library that you need to fulfill your specific task. It is not necessary to wrap each function separately. E.g. if the 3<sup>rd</sup> party native library exposes C API to get length and fill an array, your JNI can expose a method that sets a Java array.

Your wrapper will take care of conversion of Java data types (including classes) to the data types of the 3<sup>rd</sup> party library.